# How does Haste work on natural attacks?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, natural-weapon

How does *haste* work with Natural Attacks?

I was going to play a Master chemist in my game, but I ran across a problem. for those who are not familiar with the Master chemist, it is a prestige class based on the overuse of the Alchemist's mutagens creating a split personality.

The strategy this capitalizes on is the Feral Mutagen discovery, which gives you 1 bite (1d8) and 2 claws (1d6 each). The prerequisites of the Master chemist includes 3rd-level extracts, and the one that caught my eye was *haste*. I thought, "Hey, wouldn't a super speedy claw-wielding hulk be awesome?" but after some reading, I realized I couldn't find how *haste* interacted with natural attacks...

Assuming you have 2 claws and a bite when you are hasted, do you get an extra attack with your choice of natural attack. If so, do you get both claws?

The RAW for *haste* is:

> School transmutation; Level alchemist 3, bard 3, bloodrager 3, magus 3, medium 2, occultist 3, psychic 3, sorcerer/wizard 3,
> spiritualist 3, summoner 2, unchained summoner 3
>
> #### CASTING
>
> Casting Time 1 standard action Components V, S, M (a shaving of
> licorice root)
>
> #### EFFECT
>
> Range close (25 ft. + 5 ft./2 levels) Targets one creature/level, no
> two of which can be more than 30 ft. apart Duration 1 round/level
> Saving Throw Fortitude negates (harmless); Spell Resistance yes
> (harmless)
>
> #### DESCRIPTION
>
> The transmuted creatures move and act more quickly than normal. This
> extra speed has several effects.
>
> When making a full attack action, a hasted creature may make one extra
> attack with one natural or manufactured weapon. The attack is made
> using the creature’s full base attack bonus, plus any modifiers
> appropriate to the situation. (This effect is not cumulative with
> similar effects, such as that provided by a speed weapon, nor does it
> actually grant an extra action, so you can’t use it to cast a second
> spell or otherwise take an extra action in the round.)
>
> A hasted creature gains a +1 bonus on attack rolls and a +1 dodge
> bonus to AC and Reflex saves. Any condition that makes you lose your
> Dexterity bonus to Armor Class (if any) also makes you lose dodge
> bonuses.
>
> All of the hasted creature’s modes of movement (including land
> movement, burrow, climb, fly, and swim) increase by 30 feet, to a
> maximum of twice the subject’s normal speed using that form of
> movement. This increase counts as an enhancement bonus, and it affects
> the creature’s jumping distance as normal for increased speed.
> Multiple haste effects don’t stack. Haste dispels and counters slow.

As you can see, this says nothing of natural attacks, so can someone help me with this info?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is on the spell's description:

> When making a full attack action, a hasted creature may **make one extra attack with one natural** or manufactured weapon.

Pick one of your natural weapons and make one extra attack using it. It's that simple.

So, if you got a single bite attack, you can make an an additional bite attack. If you got a bite and two claws, you can either make an additional bite attack or an additional claw attack. And so on.